# Python show HTML arrows to dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, replace

I created a datframe df,

```
           Value     Change        Direction    
Date                                    
2015-03-02  2117.38   NaN              0        
2015-03-03  2107.79  -9.609864         0    
2015-03-04  2098.59  -9.250000         0    
2015-03-05  2101.04   2.510010         1    
2015-03-06  2071.26  -29.780029        0
. 
.
.
```

Now I am trying to replace the Direction value 0 by down arrow and 1 by up arrow. HTML code for down arrow is &#3219

Comment: You should use a simple map, like this: `df['Direction'] = df['Direction'].map({0:'&#3219', 1: 'codeforup'})`. Now if this shows arrows in your UI, that I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for reply @AntonvBR but it show the string '&#3219' not arrow

Comment: Don't use Html code. Just copy symbols and use it. Copy from here :- https://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/bullet-alt-codes.php

Answer (score 4):

Try below code example:

```
import pandas as pd

Fruits = ('Apple', 'Mango', 'Grapes', 'Banana', 'orange')
Price = (100, 80, 50, 90, 60)
direction = (1, 0, 1, 1, 0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': Fruits, 'Price': Price,'direction':direction})

df.direction.replace([1, 0],["&#8593;", "&#8595;"], inplace=True)    #replace the values using html codes for up and down arrow.

html_df= df.to_html()    #convert the df to html for better formatting view

html_df = html_df.replace("<td>&amp;#8595;</td>","<td><font color = red>&#8595;</font></td>")    # Remove extra tags and added red colour to down arrow
html_df = html_df.replace("<td>&amp;#8593;</td>","<td><font color = green>&#8593;</font></td>")    # Remove extra tags and added green colour to up arrow

print(html_df)    #print the df
```

Output file in browser:

[image: Output file in browser]

Comment: Thanks @Chadila07 is it possible to change the color of Direction columns for example green for up and red for down.

Comment: @aakashsingh although you haven't asked for color in your question, but yes it is possible to add color to arrows. I have editted my answer to add color to arrows also updated output. check this out.

Comment: @aakashsingh  please accept the answer if you think it answers to your question properly.

Comment: @Chandila07: if you are still active on SO, I need to ask you that this does not produce a table as shown in your output. Rather it showing me a pure html tagged code. How to fix that and see the output as you are showing here

Comment: @Django0602 on the cli or console you will see the html as text only but if want the html view (rendering) then you need to redirect the cli output to some file with .html extension and open it on the browser. you can see i have written "Output file in browser" so, this output you will see in browser only because it renders the html. I hope you understand my point...

Comment: @Chandila07: Amazing! my bad I forgot to read that! One last thing, how do I export the contents in an excel or csv and still preserve the arrows with the colour? Any idea about that?

Answer (score 3):

Use

> `df['direction'] = df['direction'].map({0: '↓', 1: '↑'})`

```
import pandas as pd

Title = ('jimmy', 'red', 'blue', 'brad', 'oranges')
value = (82, 38 , 55, 19, 33)
direction = (0, 1, 1, 0, 0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': Title, 'value': value,'direction':direction})
df['direction'] = df['direction'].map({0: '↓', 1: '↑'})
df
```

**Output**

```
    Title   value   direction
0   jimmy   82      ↓
1   red     38      ↑
2   blue    55      ↑
3   brad    19      ↓
4   oranges 33      ↓
```